# MacOS Ventura update changed terminal command location

Tags: terminal, macos-ventura

I recently updated my Mac to MacOS Ventura Beta, causing terminal commands like gcc, pyhton3 and pip3 to not work. Until last week I was able to use them normally, but after the update terminal asks me to download XCode Commandline Developer Tools.

The problem that came with this, is that VSCode is unable to find include files for C/C++.

I tried reinstalling VSCode, VSCode extensions related to C/C++, and even changing the #include_path for C files in VSCode, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be very much appreciated :).

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to put my solution here.

The new macOS Ventura is officially released now. I encountered the same issue you described. The solution was pretty simple, just to install XCode.

Run this command in `Terminal.app`:

```
xcode-select --install
```

- Let it install the XCode.
- Restart your VSCode.

You should be working correctly now.